# Multiple queries (OR statements) using find

Tags: matlab, indexing, find

Currently to perform multiple queries using `find`, I invoke each query individually separated by `|`

```
index = find(strcmp(data{:,{'type'}},'A') | strcmp(data{:,{'type'}},'B') | strcmp(data{:,{'type'}},'C') | strcmp(data{:,{'type'}},'D'));
```

To find all rows that where the field 'type' contains either A, B, C or D.

`data` is held in a table hence the usage of `}`.

Is there a more concise way of doing this without the need to specify the query in full each time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `ismember` instead of multiple uses of `strcmp`.

```
index = find(ismember(data{:,{'type'}}, {'A','B','C','D'}));
```

An alternative (because `ismember` will probably be slower than multiple uses of `strcmp`) would be to factor out the repeated code -

```
x = data{:, {'type'}}; %# This isn't valid MATLAB but whatever...
index = find(strcmp(x,'A') | strcmp(x,'B') | strcmp(x,'C') | strcmp(x,'D'));
```

You could also use multiple lines for readability

```
x = data{:, {'type'}}; %# This isn't valid MATLAB but whatever...
index = find(strcmp(x,'A') ...
           | strcmp(x,'B') ...
           | strcmp(x,'C') ...
           | strcmp(x,'D'));
```

Comment: Thanks! Out of interest can `ismember` be expanded to search across multiple fields and not just `type`?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean. Could you edit your question so that the code is valid, runnable MATLAB? That would make it easier to help you!

Comment: I'm not sure what is invalid about the code provided in the OP. It runs on my version of MATLAB without error - `type` is a field contained within `data`, which uses MATLAB's new table datatype. You've already answered my question but I was just wondering if your solution could be expanded to include multiple fields i.e. find A,B,C or D in `type` whilst also finding 6 or 7 in, for example, `type2`.

Comment: Ah, I see - I haven't used a version of MATLAB that has the table data type. I assumed that `data` was a cell array. My apologies!

Comment: I can't think of a way to do that with a single call to `ismember` but you could just combine two calls - `ismember(data{:,{'type'}}, {'A','B'}) & ismember(data{:,{'type2'}}, [6,7])` for example?

Comment: Thanks for answering! I was indeed wondering if it could be done in a single call but this is as good.